# Return distinct rows after averaging on group

Tags: sql

I have a table `MyTable` that looks something like

```
periodEndDate TotTermLoans companyName
2009-09-30    NA           ABB
2009-09-30    5.38         ABB
2009-09-30    4.34         ABB
2009-12-31    5.6          ABB
2009-12-31    5.6          ABB
2009-12-31    5.6          ABB
2010-03-31    5.47         ABB
2010-03-31    5.47         ABB
2010-03-31    5.0          ABB
```

I wish to group by year and get the average of `TotTermLoans` for each year, but with my query I get repeated rows:

```
SELECT YEAR(periodEndDate), AVG(TotTermLoans), companyName 
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY YEAR(periodEndDate)
```

which gives

```
   YEAR(periodEndDate) AVG(TotTermLoans) companyName
   2009                 5.304             ABB
   2009                 5.304             ABB
   2009                 5.304             ABB
   2010                 5.313             ABB
   2010                 5.313             ABB
   2010                 5.313             ABB
```

I would like

```
   YEAR(periodEndDate) AVG(TotTermLoans) companyName
   2009                 5.304             ABB
   2010                 5.313             ABB
```

Do I have to use sub queries for this? Thank you

Comment: include `companyname` in `group by`.

Comment: The query that you specify should return only one row per year.  I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT            YEAR(periodEndDate), AVG(TotTermLoans), companyName 
FROM              MyTable
GROUP BY          YEAR(periodEndDate), companyName
```

The `DISTINCT` keyword can also be used on `SELECT` statements to remove duplicated results.

Comment: Any reason for `distinct`? seems like the `Group By` should completely handle things.

Comment: Fair point. A bad habit I guess, but a useful SQL keyword to know nonetheless.

Comment: If I remove the `DISTINCT` from your original answer, this doesn't work for me, it gives repeated years, but if I keep it it works perfectly. I tried to distill my problem to a smaller question, maybe something got "lost" in translation underways?

Comment: That seems strange, have you simplified your query to post it here? There must be something lost in translation which is separating those rows!

Comment: Yes I simplified the query, but since it worked with `distinct` I guess I can just go with it? Thanks again